# Terminating thread in python library

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am writing a python library that will be used on unix/windows. I am facing an issue with terminating `t1` thread. I have tried setting it to `daemon` thread but because the library is sometimes used in IDE/applications, `t1` thread won't close until the whole application closes - which is not desired. Now, I am trying to change it to non-daemon thread and handle the termination manually.

```
def threadclick(id, stop):
    while(True):
        //do things repetitively //
        if stop():
           break

def main():
    global stop_thread
    stop_thread = False
    port_string1 = port_string
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=threadclick, args=(id, lambda : stop_thread))
    t1.start()
```

I need to be able to close it by calling this function:

```
def close_thread():
     global stop_thread
     stop_thread = True
     t1.join
```

of course it is giving me t1 is undefined error but I am not sure how to declare it globally.

Answer (score 1):

Passig a constant value read from a simple scalar,
rather than passing a reference, is a concern,
as you wouldn't want to keep re-reading an unchanging value.
A dict will be convenient.

The function you were using seemed a little on the complex side.

Also, you'd probably be better off passing around a reference,
rather than relying on a global.

Use this:

```
def threadclick(id, status):
    while not status['stop']:
        do_things()


status = dict(stop=False)


def main():
    status['stop'] = False
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=threadclick, args=(id, status))
    t1.start()
    wait_for_things_to_happen()
    close_thread(t1, status)


def close_thread(t1, status):
    status['stop'] = True
    t1.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to call close_thread() function without passing t1 or status? The user will be importing the library and he should call close_thread function in the end of his application without  passing args. ( I am actually combining the close_thread() function inside another library's function- serial_port.close())

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a context manager. https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager  Consider using `with closing( ... )`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing